# Registration form not working with menubar/masterpage

Tags: php, html

I am new to php.
I am trying to make a registration page.
The coding below works fine when run individually but when it is run with master page/menubar it would not even check the validations when click on submit.It would simply redirect to homepage which is not specified in the Header function.
I just decided to keep it simple and move further step by step.So it might be kind of Cheap kind of code for some of you.
Anyways, Please tell me where i am wrong and what should i do to make it run with menubar.php.
Here is my registration form code(register.php) so far.

Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center" style="height:700px; width:70%; borderstyle:solid; border-width:5px; margin:auto; background-color: #FFFFFF;">
<?php
// Initialize variables and set to empty strings
$firstName=$pass=$confpass=$gender=$city=$num=$Email="";
$firstNameErr=$passErr=$confpassErr=$cityErr=$numErr=$EmailErr=$genderErr="";

// Validate input and sanitize
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']== "POST") 
{
    $valid = true; //Your indicator for your condition, actually it depends on what you need. I am just used to this method.

   if (empty($_POST["firstName"])) {
      $firstNameErr = "First name is required";
      $valid = false; //false
   }
   else 
   {

      $firstName = test_input($_POST["firstName"]);
      if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$firstName))
        {
          $firstName = "";
          $firstNameErr = "Only letters are allowed"; 

        }
   }
    if (empty($_POST["gender"])) 
    {
      $genderErr = "Gender Required";
      $valid = false;
    }


    if (empty($_POST["Email"])) 
    {
      $EmailErr = "Email is required";
      $valid = false;
    }
   else 
   {
      $Email = test_input($_POST["Email"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["pass"])) 
   {
      $passErr = "Please enter your password";
      $valid = false;
   }

  else 
    {

   if ($_POST["confpass"] != $_POST["pass"])
    {
      $passErr = "Your passwords didnt match";
      $valid = false;
      $pass="";
      $confpass="";
    }

    } 
    if (empty($_POST["city"])) 
    {
      $cityErr = "Please enter your city";
      $valid = false;
    }
   else
    {
      $city = test_input($_POST["city"]);
    }

   if (empty($_POST["num"])) 
   {
      $numErr = "Please enter your correct number";
      $valid = false;
   }
   else 
   {
      $num = test_input($_POST["num"]);
   }


  //if valid then redirect
  if($valid)
   {
   header('Location: https://www.google.co.in');
   exit();
   }
}


// Sanitize data
function test_input($data) 
{
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>


<h2>Registration Form</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required</span></p>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">
Full Name: <input type="text" name="firstName" value="<?php echo $firstName; ?>" ><span class="error">* <?php echo $firstNameErr; ?></span><br><br>

Gender: <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Male<br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female<span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr; ?></span><br>

E-mail:  <input type="email" name="Email" value="<?php echo $Email; ?>"><span class="error">* <?php echo $EmailErr; ?><br><br></span>

Password: <input type="password" name="pass" value="<?php echo $pass; ?>"><span class="error">* <?php echo $passErr; ?><br><br></span>

Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="confpass" value="<?php echo $confpass; ?>"><span class="error">* <?php echo $confpassErr; ?><br><br></span>

City <input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $city; ?>"><span class="error">* <?php echo $cityErr; ?><br><br></span>

Contact no:  <input type="number" name="num"><span class="error">* <?php echo $numErr; ?><br><br></span>

State: 
    <select name="state"/>
     <option value="ap">Andhra Pradesh</option>
     <option value="aap">Arunachal Pradesh</option>
     <option value="as">Assam</option>
     <option value="bi">Bihar</option>
     <option value="ch">Chattisgarh</option>
     <option value="goa">Goa</option>
     <option value="Gujarat">Gujarat</option>
     <option value="Haryana">Haryana</option>
     <option value="Hp">Himachal Pradesh</option>
     <option value="Jk">Jammu and Kashmir</option>
     <option value="jh">Jharkhand</option>
     <option value="ka">Karnatka</option>
     <option value="Kerala">Kerala</option>
     <option value="MP">Madhya Pradesh</option>
     <option value="mh">Maharashtra</option>
     <option value="manipur">Manipur</option>
     <option value="Meg">Meghalya</option>
     <option value="miz">Mizoram</option>
     <option value="ng">Nagaland</option>
     <option value="or">Orissa</option>
     <option value="punjab">Punjab</option>
     <option value="rj">Rajasthan</option>
     <option value="si">Sikkim</option>
     <option value="tn">Tamil Nadu</option>
     <option value="tr">Tripura</option>
     <option value="ut">Uttaranchal</option>
     <option value="up">Uttar Pradesh</option>
     <option value="wb">West Bengal</option>
     <option value="and">Andaman And Nicobar Islands</option>
     <option value="ch">Chandigarh</option>
     <option value="delhi">Delhi</option>
     </select>
<input type="submit">
&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="reset" name="Reset">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my menubar.php code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
<?php
include("mycss/mystyle.css");
?>
</style>
</head>
<body style="font-family: verdana, sans-serif;" bgcolor="#DDDDDD";>
<br>
<ul>
<li><a href="menubar.php?page=home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="menubar.php?page=about">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="menubar.php?page=Product">Our Product</a></li>
<li><a href="menubar.php?page=contact">Contact Us</a></li>
<ul style="float:right; list-style-type:none; border:none; border-left:1px solid #C0C0C0;">
<li><a href="menubar.php?page=index1">Login</a></li>
<li><a href="menubar.php?page=register">Register</a></li>   
</ul>
</ul>
<hr />
<div style="width: 100%; height: auto;border: 1px solid #BDBDBD;">

<?php
      if(isset($_GET['page']))
      {
          $page_name=$_GET['page'];
          include("pages/".$page_name.".php");
      }
      else
          include("pages/home.php");
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in register.php:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">
```

Replace to:

```
<form action="menubar.php?page=register" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

In menubar.php you're not sanitizing page parameter properly .. It's vulnerable to File Inclusion/Dir Traversal .. 
For example .. ?page=../../../../../../etc/passwd%00

You can do something like this to protect it against those sorta vulns:

```
<?php
      if(isset($_GET['page']))
      {
          $page_name = htmlentities($_GET['page']);
          include("pages/".$page_name.".php");
      }
      else
          include("pages/home.php");
?>
```

Or this if you don't have too many "pages" ..

```
<?php
$files = array('foo', 'bar');
$page_name = htmlentities($_GET['page']);
$safe = in_array($page_name, $files) ? $page_name : 'home';
include('pages/'.$safe.'.php');
?>
```

As for the question itself ah, you don't have to have an "action" attribute in register.php if the action is going to be the same page ... but you can set it to "#"

Comment: Thank you Abk Khan, 
I will consider these things later.